# "apk index" Command Reports 0 Packages Despite Index File Containing Entries

Tags: alpine-linux

I am encountering an unusual issue with the apk index command. When running the apk index command to create an index of APK packages, the command consistently reports "0 packages" in the index, although new packages are being added (as indicated by the command itself and confirmed by inspecting the APKINDEX.tar.gz file). Here is the command I am using:

```
apk index --merge --verbose --update-cache --allow-untrusted --no-interactive -x APKINDEX.tar.gz -o APKINDEX.tar.gz ./*.apk
```

The output I receive indicates that packages are being processed and added, but the total count remains at 0.

```
Index has 0 packages (of which 20 are new)
```

Upon inspecting the contents of the APKINDEX.tar.gz file, it's clear that it contains entries for various packages. Fetching those packages works, too. Rerunning, end up with an increased number of ... Y are new)", but the beginning is always the same: Index has 0 packages ...

Why might the apk index command report "0 packages" in the index despite the index file containing package entries?